# update tkinter window with gif

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from itertools import count
from time import sleep

class ImageLabel(tk.Label):

    def load(self, im):
        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)
        self.loc = 0
        self.frames = []

        try:
            for i in count(1):
                self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
                im.seek(i)

        except EOFError:
            pass

        try:
            self.delay = im.info['10']
        except:
            self.delay = 100

        if len(self.frames) == 1:
            self.config(image=self.frames[0])          
        else:
            for i in range(1):
                self.next_frame()

    def unload(self):
        self.config(image=None)
        self.frames = None

    def next_frame(self):
        if self.frames:
            self.loc += 1
            self.loc %= len(self.frames)
            self.config(image=self.frames[self.loc])
            self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')
root.title("מערכת הסבת וואלה מייל")
lbl = ImageLabel(root)
lbl.pack()
lbl.load('Logo.gif')
```

I ran this code and I don't know how to update the tkinter win after one shows the gif.

Can someone help me and tell me how to do this? I tried many things and I don't  know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this program in IDLE it seems to work fine. The thing that IDLE does that is not in the program is running the mainloop. Try adding as the last line in the program:

```
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it's work fine. i ask how after it's run i update the tk win to stop run gif and replace to input row..

Comment: Please start a new question instead of continuing here. This will allow people to see that a new question is asked as this one is already answered.